# Select que depende de otro trato de hacerlo de un ejemplo que tengo

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenos dias amigo aca tengo un select option que necesito que dependa de otro pero no me sale necesito ayuda trato de hacer este ejemplo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOgYmE

```
tds += '<select class="form-control"  id="choice1">';
tds += '<option value="C">ESTRUCTURAL</option>';
tds += '<option value="S">ESTRUCTURAL</option>';
tds += '<option value="O">ORGANIZATIVA</option>';
tds += ' <option value="AF"  >OTROS FACTORES</option>';
tds += '</select>';



                    tds += '<select class="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria" id="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria">';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" disabled selected></option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="" value="" disabled>CONDUCTAL</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title=" Incumplimiento de normas procedimientos y metodos de trabajo"   value="C1">C1</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Falta de uso, mal uso o uso incorrecto de los EPI" value="C2">C2</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Uso indebido los equipos y dispositivos" value="C3">C3</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Posicion inadecuada del cuerpo /postura"  value="C4">C4</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Distraccion / Falta de atencion"  value="C5">C5</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Falta de señalizacion de peligro"  value="C6">C6</option>';


                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title=""  value="" disabled>ESTRUCTURAL</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title="Equipos/ Herramientas / Dispositivos defectuosos o inadecuadas."  value="S1">S1</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title="Falta/Insuficiencia de los dispositivos de proteccion colectiva."  value="S2">S2</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title=" Sistemas inadecuado de prevencion de explosiones o incendios."  value="S3">S3</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title="Inadecuada contencion de productos quimicos."  value="S4">S4</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title="Inadecuado sistema de señalizacion de peligros."  value="S5">S5</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="S" title="Condiciones inadecuadas del ambiente de trabajo."  value="S6">S6</option>';




                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title=""  value="" disabled>ORGANIZATIVA</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Falta de procedimiento / procedimiento inadecuado."  value="01">01</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Evaluacion de riesgos incompleta"  value="02">O2</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title=" Inadecuada demarcacion de las areas"  value="03">O3</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Inadecuado mantenimiento de los dispositivos y equipos o herramientas"  value="04">O4</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Gestion adecuada de los EPI´S"  value="05">O5</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Falta/Inadecuacion del sistema de control/Monitoreo"  value="06">O6</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Utilizacion de mano de obra no cualificada."  value="07">O7</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Falta de formacion/formacion insuficiente."  value="08">O8</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Falta de coordinación entre actividades o de definicion de responsabilidades."  value="09">O9</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Falta de orden / limpieza de lugares de trabajo."  value="10">10</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="O" title="Proceso de comunicación inadecuado."  value="11">11</option>';




                        tds += '<option data-option="AF"  title=""  value="" disabled   >OTROS FACTORES</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="AF"  title="Fenomenos naturales imprevistos"  value="AF1">AF1</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="AF"  title="Crimen/delincuencia"  value="AF2">AF2</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="AF"  title="Perdida de conocimiento/ Control sensorial"  value="AF3">AF3</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="AF"  title="Otros"  value="AF4">AF4</option>';
```

Y ESTE ES MI JAVASCRIPT

```
function filter_options(){
    if (typeof $("#choice1").data('options') === "undefined") {
       $("#choice1").data('options', $('#txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria_ option').clone());
  }
    var id = $("#choice1").val();
    var options = $("#choice1").data('options').filter('[data-option=' +val.idPre + ']');
    $('#txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria_').html(options);
}

$(function () {
        //Ejecutar el filtro la primera vez
        filter_options();

    //actualizar al cambiar el factor
    $("#choice1").change(function () {
        filter_options();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en que como estas armando varias veces el combo principal osea el **#choice1** te genera un conflicto porque no existe solo uno pueden exitir varios, para solventar invocalos por la clase **.choice1** por ejemplo.  Hice unos cambios en tu código pruebalo y me avisas:

```
function filter_options(e){

  const padre = $(e.target).parent();
  if (typeof padre.find(".choice1").data('options') === "undefined") {
    padre.find(".choice1").data('options', padre.find('.combo2').clone());
  }

  var id = padre.find(".combo1").val();
  var options = padre.find(".combo1").data('options').filter('[data-option=' +val.idPre + ']');
  padre.find('.combo2').html(options);

}

$(function () {

  $(".combo1").change((e) => {
    filter_options(e);
  });

});
```

Como son varios **.combo1** y por cada uno de ellos hay un **.combo2** entonces le paso a la función **filter_options** el elemento quien esta desencadenando el evento **change**, luego dentro de la función llamo a un instancia superior que llamo **padre** para luego obtener los hijos dinamicamente según la fila correspondiente y así no mezclamos los combos **.combo1** entre si y debería de llamar al combo2 correspondiente a su fila y no a otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias David Leonardo Molina ese ejercicio me funciono a la perfeccion